# mingw64 Makefile:5: *** missing separator

Tags: makefile, window, gnu-make, mingw-w64

I'm using mingw64 in Windows trying to invoke Makefile to run Go
but keep getting:

```
Makefile:5: *** missing separator.
```

This is the Makefile:

```
BINARY_NAME=celeritasApp.exe

## build: builds all binaries
build:
    @go mod vendor
    @go build -o tmp/${BINARY_NAME} .
    @echo Celeritas built!

run: build
    @echo Staring Celeritas...
    @.\tmp\${BINARY_NAME} &
    @echo Celeritas started!

clean:
    @echo Cleaning...
    @go clean
    @del .\tmp\${BINARY_NAME}
    @echo Cleaned!

test:
    @echo Testing...
    @go test ./...
    @echo Done!

start: run
    
stop:
    @echo "Starting the front end..."
    @taskkill /IM ${BINARY_NAME} /F
    @echo Stopped Celeritas

restart: stop start
```

The make version:

```
xxxx@xxxxx MSYS /c/dev/my/go_apps/myapp
$ make --version
GNU Make 4.3
Built for x86_64-pc-msys
Copyright (C) 1988-2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Comment: This is the single most common problem in makefiles, by many orders of magnitude.  Did you try googling for "make missing separator"?  What about those answers didn't help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indents in `Makefile` must be real **tab** characters, **not spaces**.